# Hide axis label only, not entire axis, in Pandas plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib

I can clear the text of the `xlabel` in a Pandas plot with:

```py
plt.xlabel("")
```

Instead, is it possible to hide the label?

May be something like `.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[From the Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot) -

> The plot method on Series and DataFrame is just a simple wrapper around plt.plot():

This means that anything you can do with matplolib, you can do with a Pandas DataFrame plot.

[pyplot has an `axis()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis) method that lets you set axis properties. Calling `plt.axis('off')` before calling `plt.show()` will turn off **both** axes.

```
df.plot()
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

To control a single axis, you need to set its properties via the plot's [Axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib-axes).  For the x axis - [(pyplot.axes().get_xaxis().....](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis))

```
df.plot()
ax1 = plt.axes()
x_axis = ax1.axes.get_xaxis()
x_axis.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Similarly to control an axis label, get the label and turn it off.

```
df.plot()
ax1 = plt.axes()
x_axis = ax1.axes.get_xaxis()
x_axis.set_label_text('foo')
x_label = x_axis.get_label()
##print isinstance(x_label, matplotlib.artist.Artist)
x_label.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

You can also get to the x axis like this

```
ax1 = plt.axes()
x_axis = ax1.xaxis
x_axis.set_label_text('foo')
x_axis.label.set_visible(False)
```

Or this

```
ax1 = plt.axes()
ax1.xaxis.set_label_text('foo')
ax1.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
```

---

[DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

> returns a [matplotlib.axes.Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/axes_api.html) or numpy.ndarray of them

so you can *get* it/them when you call it.

```
axs = df.plot()
```

---

`.set_visible()` is an [Artist](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html#artist-tutorial) method.  The axes and their labels are Artists so they have [Artist methods/attributes](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#artists) as well as [their own](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis).  There are many ways to customize your plots.  Sometimes you can find the feature you want browsing the [Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and [Examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html#matplotlib-examples)

Answer (score 11):

You can remove axis labels and ticks using `xlabel=` or `ylabel=` arguments in the `plot()` call. For example, to remove the xlabel, use `xlabel=''`:

```py
df.plot(xlabel='');
```

[image: res1]

To remove the x-axis ticks, use `xticks=[]` (for y-axis ticks, use `yticks=`):

```py
df.plot(xticks=[]);
```

[image: res2]

To remove both:

```py
df.plot(xticks=[], xlabel='');
```

[image: res3]