# how to hide plotly yaxis title (in python)?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

**Editing:**
The following example from Plotly for reference:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
fig = px.bar(df, y='pop', x='country', text='pop')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide')
fig.show()
```

How to remove the word 'pop'.

---

What I want to hide the y-axis title of'value'.

[image]
The following syntax doesn't work.

```
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)
```

Thanks.

Comment: this question already ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705614/hide-axis-label-only-not-entire-axis-in-pandas-plot

Comment: @JaiMahesh Your answer seems to be about `pandas`, this question is about `plotly`. Does your solution work for `plotly` too?

Comment: hi all, the solution both does not solve the problem.It is Plotly by the way guys, the plt does not work.

Comment: please  put some code content .

Comment: example code added

Comment: Hi Patrick, the text = '' will still remain the space there. The reason why I want to remove it is that the screen size for mobile is limited and I want to save some space to remove it literally. '

Comment: _How to remove the word 'pop'._   vs  _`What I want to hide the y-axis title of'value'._  ? Both should go? Where is pop on the image?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am sorry that it is misleading in my question. I mean remove it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Solution

You need to use `visible=False` inside `fig.update_yaxes()` or
`fig.update_layout()` as follows. For more details see the
documentation for [plotly.graph_objects.Figure](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html).

```py
# Option-1:  using fig.update_yaxes()
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False, showticklabels=False)

# Option-2: using fig.update_layout()
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False})

# Option-3: using fig.update_layout() + dict-flattening shorthand
fig.update_layout(yaxis_visible=False, yaxis_showticklabels=False)
```

Try doing the following to test this:

```py
# Set the visibility ON
fig.update_yaxes(title='y', visible=True, showticklabels=False)
# Set the visibility OFF
fig.update_yaxes(title='y', visible=False, showticklabels=False)
```

### A. How to create the figure directly with hidden-yaxis label and tickmarks

You can do this directly by using the `layout` keyword and
supplying a `dict` to `go.Figure()` constructor.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displaying Itself",
    layout = {'xaxis': {'title': 'x-label',
                        'visible': True,
                        'showticklabels': True},
              'yaxis': {'title': 'y-label',
                        'visible': False,
                        'showticklabels': False}
              }
)
fig
```

[image]

### B. How to create the figure without the margin space around

Say, you suppressed the titles for both the axes. By default `plotly`
would still leave a default amount of space all around the figure:
*this is known as the `margin`* in Plotly's documention.

> What if you want to reduce or even completely remove the margin?

This can be done using `fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l = ..., r = ..., t = ..., b = ...))` as mentioned in the documentation:

- https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-margin.

In the following example, I have reduced the `left`, `right`
and `bottom` margins to `10 px` and set the `top` margin to `50 px`.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure with no axis-title and modified margins",
    layout = {
        'xaxis': {'title': 'x-label',
                'visible': False,
                'showticklabels': True},
        'yaxis': {'title': 'y-label',
                'visible': False,
                'showticklabels': False},
        # specify margins in px
        'margin': dict(
            l = 10,        # left
            r = 10,        # right
            t = 50,        # top
            b = 10,        # bottom
        ),
    },
)
fig
```

[image: plotly-figure-with-no-axis-titles-and-reduced-margins]

### C. An Interesting Feature of Plotly: *A hidden shorthand*

It turns out that Plotly has a convenient shorthand notation
allowing *dict-flattening* available for input arguments such as this:

```py
## ALL THREE METHODS BELOW ARE EQUIVALENT

# No dict-flattening
# layout = dict with yaxis as key
layout = {'yaxis': {'title': 'y-label',
                    'visible': False,
                    'showticklabels': False}
}

# Partial dict-flattening
# layout_yaxis = dict with key-names
#     title, visible, showticklabels
layout_yaxis = {'title': 'y-label',
                'visible': False,
                'showticklabels': False}

# Complete dict-flattening
# layout_yaxis_key-name for each of the key-names
layout_yaxis_title = 'y-label'
layout_yaxis_visible = False
layout_yaxis_showticklabels = False
```

Now try running all three of the following and compare the outputs.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Method-1: Shortest (less detailed)
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displaying Itself",
    layout_yaxis_visible = False,
    layout_xaxis_title = 'x-label'
)
fig.show()

# Method-2: A hibrid of dicts and underscore-separated-syntax
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displaying Itself",
    layout_xaxis_title = 'x-label',
    layout_yaxis = {'title': 'y-label',
                        'visible': False,
                        'showticklabels': False}
)
fig.show()

# Method-3: A complete dict syntax
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displaying Itself",
    layout = {'xaxis': {'title': 'x-label',
                        'visible': True,
                        'showticklabels': True},
              'yaxis': {'title': 'y-label',
                        'visible': False,
                        'showticklabels': False}
              }
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: While this does hide the label, it does not fix the issue on mobile devices. The graphs still end up being the same width with or without the label visible. Is there a known way to remove it instead of hiding the visibility to make the graphs wider?

Comment: Just an idea: try setting the axes labels as empty strings. May be that will work. For example, `layout_xaxis_title = ''`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too but nothing. I'm looking into modifying the graphs in JS instead of Python now.

Comment: @DarkHark Perhaps what you are looking for is adjusting the margin around the figure. That can be done using `fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l = ..., r = ..., t = ..., b = ...))` as mentioned in the documentation: https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-margin.

Comment: @DarkHark I have updated the answer now with the margin-manipulation. Please take a look at the newly added section ***B. How to create the figure without the margin space around***.

Comment: yes! I didn't think to look at the margins. Great solution, thank you!

Comment: When you set 'visible': False to update_xaxes, you hide not only the title, but also thick labels and other axis configurations. @saaj's answer below in fact hides the title, only.

Answer (score 27):

> How to remove the word 'pop'?

Just pass `yaxis_title=None` to `fig.update_layout` to hide default title of Y axis  (similarly for `xaxis_title=None` for X axis).

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
fig = px.bar(df, y='pop', x='country', text='pop')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide', yaxis_title=None)
fig.show()
```

[image: hide title of Y axis]

Comment: `fig.update_layout(yaxis_title=None)` worked for me